# Regular expression - starting with this letter only

Tags: regex

i am writing a regular expression that should start with `EM` and `underscore` `any number of digits`

so here is what i have: and needs to help to correct the regexpression:
`"^[em-EM]{2}_[0-9]"`

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtId" ValidationExpression="^[em-EM]{2}_[0-9]" ErrorMessage="Invalid Id" Display="Dynamic"> </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

don't use the - like that:

```
"^(em|EM)_\d*"
```

Answer (score 2):

If case doesn't matter:

```
"^[eE][mM]_[0-9]*$"
```

Answer (score 1):

straight solution (for .Net) would be:

```
(?i)^EM_\d*$
```

broken down:

```
(?i)      # case insensitive mode
^         # beginning of line (you've got that right)
EM        # characters "em"
_         # underscore
\d*       # zero or more digits
$         # end of line
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `(?i)(?-i)`, so you don't need to specify for the sensitive case on the string:

```
"^(?i)em(?-i)\x5F\d*$"
```

Comment: sure, but you don't need to restrict the case sensitivity to the letters, because the rest of the expression is caseless...

Comment: @CodeJockey right, Is not needed. But I still consider this a good practice.